# Should I share my library between Microservices?

Tags: microservices, clean-architecture

I gain my first experience with Microservices and need help on an important descision.

Example: We have

- CustomerService (contains CustomerDTO)
- InvoiceService (contains CustomerDTO, InvoiceDTO)
- PrintService (contains CustomerDTO, InvoiceDTO)

As you see I have a heavy Code Duplication here, each time I modify CustomerDTO, I need to do it in 3 different Microservices.

My potential solution is, to exclude the duplicated classes into a library and share this library between microservices. But in my opinion this will break the microservice approach.

So, what is the right way to handle my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single right way to solve this problem as with most things. There are pros and cons to each approach depending on your circumstances.

Here are probably your main options

1. Create a new common service:

   If your logic is sufficiently complex, you have many services that need this logic, and you have time on your hands then look to creating a common service that will fulfill this need. This may not be a small undertaking as you now have to create one more service you need to manage/deploy/scale
2. Just accept the duplication:

   This may seem counter-intuitive, however if the logic is sufficiently small enough it may be better to just duplicate it rather than couple your micro-services with a library
3. Create the library

   Real life is different than the textbooks. We are often constrained by time and budget among other things. If your micro-services are small enough and you know this logic will not change as much, or you just need to get things out and duplication would take more time. Take this approach. There is nothing to say you can't address this later when you have the time/budget. Countless blog articles will scream at you for doing this however, they aren't you and don't know the circumstances of your project.

Comment: This is answer though sounds correct for some situation considering the question mentions DTOs explicitely I would say it is wrong. You should not create shared library for DTOs which I am assuming kind of contract in between your microservices.

Comment: @cool if it's just the case of the DTO themselves I agree with you. However, I assumed he also meant handling the logic with these objects as well